# Corona: Error on removing event listeners from runtime during destroy

Tags: mobile, lua, coronasdk

I am cleaning up a scene in Corona and attempting to remove the event listeners in the destroy event for the scene. I've added the events in the show event for the scene, as follows:

```
function scene:show(event)
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", onFrame)
    Runtime:addEventListener("touch", onTap)
    Runtime:addEventListener("collision", onCollision)
end

function scene:destroy(event)
    Runtime.removeEventListener("enterFrame", onFrame)
    Runtime.removeEventListener("touch", onTap)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("collision", onCollision)
end
```

I'm getting a null pointer in the destroy event:

```
?:0: attempt to index field '_super' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    ?: in function 'removeEventListener'
```

What "_super" is it trying to access, and why is it nil? I've checked and all of the functions listed above (onFrame, onTap, and onCollision) are not nil. If anyone has any idea what's going on here, please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you've mistyped when calling removeEventListener.

See: 
Runtime **.** removeEventListener()  vs
Runtime **:** removeEventListener()

When you call removeEventListener with '.' (dot), then Runtime reference isn't passed implicitly as first argument to removeEventListener().

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that. Also can't believe Google had zero results when I searched for "corona "attempt to index field '_super'""...surely this must be a common error. Thank you for the help!